# Can GPU counters be read transparently to the application code

Tags: cuda, gpu, performancecounter

I am trying to profile the CUDA  rodinia benchmarks  executing on a GTX 650.
I am using the code /usr/local/cuda-5.0/extras/CUPTI/samples/event_sampling to read
the instructions executed counter. It seems strange that I do not see any change in the
values reported by the event_sampling whether I am executing the CUDA benchmarks or not.

The event_sampling code also has some calculations of its own for which it measures the instructions executed. Unlike CPU, do I need to make changes to the source code of the application to be able to read the GPU counters such as instruction_executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUPTI will only give you counter updates for kernels in the same process.  You can get some of these values, though not to the same level of precision, with the NVIDIA visual profiler or related environment variables without modifying the code however.

Comment: @njustn-That means without modifying the source code, I cannot read the counter events? Also, what API's does nvprof uses to provide these counter values without modifying the source code?

Comment: There is no "API" as such, but there are environment variables.  This DrDobbs article on it (http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/cuda-supercomputing-for-the-masses-part/209601096?pgno=2) is slightly out of date, but should start you in the right direction.  As far as I know there is no way for one program to monitor the counters of another in real time, but this would let you dump the counters for analysis later.  If it needs to be real-time, it has to be in with the code being run.

Comment: nvprof injects code into the running process through the CUDA driver. nvprof uses CUPTI SDK to program and collect the results. You can achieve the same results by injecting your code into the running process using binary code instrumentation (detours, pin), DLL interposer libraries, of LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: @njustn I tried to use the method you have described. My cuda_profile_config file just has a single instructions line. Then I ran a Rodinia benchmark and I got a log file NV_Warning: Ignoring the invalid profiler config option: instructions
# CUDA_PROFILE_LOG_VERSION 2.0
# CUDA_DEVICE 0 GeForce GTX 650
# CUDA_CONTEXT 1
# TIMESTAMPFACTOR fffff680e157cc60
method,gputime,cputime,occupancy
method=[ memcpyHtoD ] gputime=[ 1.152 ] cputime=[ 9.000 ]
method=[ memcpyHtoD ] gputime=[ 0.864 ] cputime=[ 12.000 ]
I actually want to get the number of instructions executed via a C code. How to do it?

Comment: @Greg Smith- Could you please explain this in a little more detail?I am seeing a tool http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool. How can I use this tool to achieve my goal of transparently reading the event counters. The method described in the link http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/cuda-supercomputing-for-the-masses-part/209601096?pgno=2 gives let's say instructions executed routine wise rather than a fixed time slice.

Comment: @VaibhavSundriyal DLL interception through the dynamic loader or binary code patching is a very complicated topic that is far beyond the scope of a stackoverflow answer. Using these techniques you can modify the behavior of the program to allow you to insert a background thread into a process to collect additional information. If you are on Linux you can read about LD_PRELOAD or read the pin user manual. If you are on windows I would suggest reading up on detours.